# How to convert as pdf using payday gemfile in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using payday gem and i write coding in controller and my code is

```
class pdfController < ApplicationController
def index
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    send_data invoice.render_pdf, :filename => "Invoice #12.pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline"
   end
  end
end
```

i don't know what to do further, any idea

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: undefined local variable or method 'invoice'. This i get

Comment: What else is in your controller?

Comment: The above coding only be in controller

Comment: So no `def show #more code end`?  Have you found the invoice you're trying to render?

Comment: i did not add any code for payday gemfile, i just install the gem only. if u know coding post it.

Comment: Please post the entire controller code.

Comment: i already told. I posted the entire code.

Comment: Really so you don't have `InvoicesController < ApplicationController`?

Comment: now, i edit in my question the entire controller coding.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to initialize the invoice instance.

```
invoice = Payday::Invoice.new(:invoice_number => 12)
invoice.line_items << LineItem.new(:price => 20, :quantity => 5, :description => "Pants")
invoice.line_items << LineItem.new(:price => 10, :quantity => 3, :description => "Shirts")
invoice.line_items << LineItem.new(:price => 5, :quantity => 200, :description => "Hats")
invoice.render_pdf_to_file("/path/to_file.pdf")
```

Above code is just an example given in payday docs.

Comment: inside index action of pdfs_controller.rb

Comment: You will need to have a line items model

Answer (score 0):

In config/initializers/mime_types.rb:

> `Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf`

I am assuming you have added the routes and put above code inside some action of controller. In view, put a link pointing to  routes of pdf rendering action which you have defined above.

I did not get your question properly, is any issue occuring?

Comment: i added this. but i get an error as "NameError" in my controller

Comment: What did u added in controller? can u paste all content of controller?

Comment: i just want to export the report as pdf format using payday gemfile. if you know coding, kindly post it.